# Load More Custom Posts On Click Ajax WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to create a load more button that loads more custom post types on click, however, I keep receiving a 400 (Bad Request) error. Here is the code i'm using.

```
// Header.php
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); class="no-js">
 <head>
    <!-- meta tags & links --->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      ajaxurl = <?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>;
```

```
// HTML:

 <div class="project">
    <?php 
        $posts_array = array(
          'post_type' => 'project',
          'status' => 'publish',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'paged' => $paged
        );
       $posts = get_posts($posts_array);
       $count = 0;
     ?>
       <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : $count++; ?>
         <div class="project">
            <php echo the_title(); ?>
         </div>
       <?php endforeach; wp_reset_query(); ?>
 </div>

 <button id="more_posts">Load More</button>

// JavaScript:

    $("#more_posts").on("click", function() {
      // When btn is pressed.
     $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        action: "more_post_ajax",
        offset: page * ppp + 1,
         ppp: ppp
      }).success(function(posts) {
        page++;
        $(".projects").append(posts);
      });
    });

// Functions.php

  function more_post_ajax(){
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];
    $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
    header("Content-Type: text/html");

     $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
         'status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'offset' => $offset,
     );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post(); 
       the_title();
    }

     exit; 
  }
```

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); 
  add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good amount here to fix.

Your Ajax is syntax is off a bit.  Also, you can specify posts per page for the return with PHP, so you don't need to send that, you can keep your page attribute on the frontend.

```
$("#more_posts").on("click", function(e) {


     $.ajax({
        // use the ajax object url
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data: {
        action: "more_post_ajax", // add your action to the data object
        offset: page * 4 //  page # x your default posts per page
        },
        success: function(data) {
         // add the posts to the container and add to your page count
         page++;
         $('.projects').append(data);

        },
        error: function(data) {
         // test to see what you get back on error
         console.log(data);
        }
     });

});
```

For your initial PHP function, you should only specify the amount of posts you want to show *at first*.  If you use -1 it will just show all posts at the start, which you don't want.  You also don't need to use the paged parameter.  You only need offsets.

```
<?php 
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'project',
          'status' => 'publish',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'posts_per_page' => 4,
        );
       $posts = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<div class="projects">

   <?php
   while ($posts->have_posts()) {
       $posts->the_post(); ?>

   <div class="project">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
   </div>

   <?php
   wp_reset_postdata();
    }; ?>

</div>
```

For your more posts function, you only need to specify an offset, and can add your additional posts right in that function.

```
function more_post_ajax(){
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];


     $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
         'status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => 4,
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'offset' => $offset,
     );

    $post = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($post->have_posts()) { $post->the_post(); 
       <div class="project">the_title();</div>
    }

   wp_reset_postdata();

     die(); // use die instead of exit 
  }

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

I have not tested this, but this should get you closer to a working set.

Comment: thank you so much for the thorough answer! I'm new to ajax and you explained this really well for me. Going to test make changes at work on monday :D Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is looking at this in the future and aren't sure on why they can't make it work theres a couple of things that need changing in the above code for starters in the js you need to define the variable page before the on click function...

```
 var page = 1;

 $("#more_posts").on("click", function(e) {


     $.ajax({
        // use the ajax object url
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data: {
        action: "more_post_ajax", // add your action to the data object
        offset: page * 4 //  page # x your default posts per page
        },
        success: function(data) {
         // add the posts to the container and add to your page count
         page++;
         $('.projects').append(data);

        },
        error: function(data) {
         // test to see what you get back on error
         console.log(data);
        }
     });

});
```

This code appends the data to the admin-ajax url which means you have to use $_GET not $_POST to retrieve the offset variable in your php function:

```
$offset = $_GET["offset"];
```